# sDNA preparation network preparation fails

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sdna

sDNA always fails when I run prepare network or integral analysis with a bit larger network system. I have to keep the model very small to complete process successfully.

How could I solve this?

[image]

Comment: A tip when posting messages from ArcGIS geoprocessing results: right click on 'Messages'  (seen above at the top of the results window) will allow copying them all to paste here as text.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the sDNA log output posted above:

```
Error: polyline 81042 has multiple parts
Please run ArcToolbox -> Data Management -> Features -> Multipart to Singlepart to fix the input feature class before running sDNA
```

Your dataset contains one or more multipart features which must be split into multiple single-part features before running any sDNA tool. ArcGIS "Multipart to singlepart" tool will achieve the desired result.